# ¿Cómo ampliar el tamaño de dos columnas para que ocupen todo el espacio de una página en Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Necesito dividir en dos partes iguales una página. En una parte va el logo de la empresa y en la otra el login.
 Ya tengo dividida la pantalla en dos columnas al interno de una fila, pero la altura de las columnas no ocupa toda la pantalla.

Debería quedar de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutar el código queda de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
  <body>
    
      <div class="row">
        <div
          class="col"
          style="background-color: #191b32"
        >
          columna 1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h4 class="text-center">SISTEMA DE INFORMACION ABC</h4>
          <form method="POST" action="index.html">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
              <input
                type="email"
                class="form-control"
                required
                id=""
                placeholder="Usuario o correo electronico"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1"></label>
              <input
                type="password"
                required
                class="form-control"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
                placeholder="Contraseña"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Iniciar sección
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Todo lo que necesitas se puede realizar utilizando las clases que Bootstrap nos da.**

Para hacer que un elemento ocupe el 100% de la altura debes usar la clase `vh-100` y luego para centrar los elementos verticalmente al interno de una columna puedes usar la clase `my-auto`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo utilizando el código que proveíste y aportándole unas pequeñas modificas:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center vh-100 w-100">

    <div class="col-6" style="background-color: #191b32">
        columna 1
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 my-auto">
        <h4 class="text-center">SISTEMA DE INFORMACION ABC</h4>
        <form method="POST" action="index.html">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1"></label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    required
                    id=""
                    placeholder="Usuario o correo electronico"
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1"></label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    required
                    class="form-control"
                    id="exampleInputPassword1"
                    placeholder="Contraseña"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Iniciar sección
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!--//col-->
</div><!--//row-->
```